# issue in send multi part sms

Tags: sms, multipart, at-command, pdu

Please help me.

Here is my PDU

> Part 1
>   079129330300150551000B923053343013F30000FFA00608040B9C020174747A0E4ACF41F4F29C0E6ACFCF203A3A3D07A5E7207A794E07B5E767101D9D9E83D27310BD3CA783DAF333888E4ECF41E939885E9ED341EDF9194447A7E7A0F41C442FCFE9A0F6FC0CA2A3D373507A0EA297E774507B7E06D1D1E939283D07D1CB733AA83D3F83E8E8F41C949E83E8E5391DD49E9F4174747A0E4ACF41F4F29C0E6ACFCF
>
> Part 2
>   079129330300150551000B923053343013F30000FF210608040B9C0202203A3A3D07A5E7207A794E07B5E767101D9D9E83D273

I am using D-link GSM modem to send but part 1 send successfully from system but not received on mobile and part 2 not send from system give unknown error.

Comment: Did you use a library to encode the concatenated SMS or did you encode by hand?

Comment: i pick some code from NET to encode.

Comment: I have send This code successfully now. but here is another problem , this Message sent only to one mobile Network "U-fon" (in pakistan). but unable to send same SMS to other networks.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate thing that I spotted is that the TP-MR field is not being incremented.

```
079129330300150551 >> 00 << 0B923053343013F30000FFA00608040B9C020174747A0E4ACF41F4F29C0E6ACFCF203A3A3D07A5E7207A794E07B5E767101D9D9E83D27310BD3CA783DAF333888E4ECF41E939885E9ED341EDF9194447A7E7A0F41C442FCFE9A0F6FC0CA2A3D373507A0EA297E774507B7E06D1D1E939283D07D1CB733AA83D3F83E8E8F41C949E83E8E5391DD49E9F4174747A0E4ACF41F4F29C0E6ACFCF

079129330300150551 >> 00 << 0B923053343013F30000FF210608040B9C0202203A3A3D07A5E7207A794E07B5E767101D9D9E83D273
```

TP-MR is the Message reference specified in the 3GPP 03.40 document:

> The TP Message Reference field gives an integer representation of a reference number of the SMS SUBMIT or SMS COMMAND submitted to the SC by the MS. The MS increments TP Message Reference by 1 for each SMS SUBMIT or SMS COMMAND being submitted. The value to be used for each SMS SUBMIT is obtained by reading the Last Used TP MR value from the SMS Status data field in the SIM (see GSM 11.11) and incrementing this value by 1. After each SMS SUBMIT has been submitted to the network, the Last Used TP MR value in the SIM is updated with the TP MR that was used in the SMS SUBMIT operation. The reference number may possess values in the range 0 to 255. The value in the TP MR assigned by the MS is the same value which is received at the SC.

A possible reason why I may work through some network operators is that they have different implementations of SMS decoders / encoders. Some are more strict than others.

If you try changing TP-MR on the second part of 01 this "might" work.

Alternatively it could be a problem in how the 7-Bit UD (text of message) has been encoded. If this is the case I can have another look. But please try the TP-MR fix out first.